# what is the place of issue of a passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu-citizens, passport, italian-citizens

I am an Italian citizen who lives in the UK.

when applying for an Indian Visa (or any other Visa) they ask for the `place of issue` of my passport.

That is the Italian consulate in London UK.

what is the right answer to this question?

Is it `London Uk` or `Italy`?

[image]

Comment: It's not befitting that you portray your passport number...you never know...just an advice.

Comment: I have now removed my passport number, thank you

Comment: Next time be very wary of what you do with your personal information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your passport's data page (the page with your picture) displays an entry for "Autorità/Authority/Autorité." As noted in the comments below, the entry there is likely to display "Ministro Degli Affari Esteri," the Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs, as the issuing governmental agency. The Passport itself does not say where (physically) the passport was issued.

If in this Indian visa application you may only choose "London (UK)" or "Italy" as the "place of issuance," I'd say the correct response is "London."

Comment: The entry is actually "Autorità/Authority/Autorité" (there is no Spanish on the biodata page), and it says "Il ministro degli affari esteri" or "ministro affari esteri," both meaning "the ministry of foreign affairs."  It's preprinted on the form, so it's the same for all passports.  That is not a place; it is a government body.

Comment: @phoog Not so in all passports. My US passport was issued 2012, and I just looked with a magnifying glass. The word is indeed "autoridad." Those three words are in the same preprinted font and weight as the words such as "Nationality / Nationalité / Nacionalidad" which appear next to the personal information added upon issuance. The words "United States Department of State," however, are printed in the same font as the personal information, suggesting that a passport issued in another place (mine came from the NPC in Sterling VA) would show another physical location.

Comment: The question is about Italian passports.  Of course other countries' passports will be different.

Comment: @phoog That is indeed correct, the OP's passport will be different. I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means the place where it's been physically issued to you, so it can be any country other than Italy, otherwise they wouldn't have put the option to begin with if every Italian passport was issued in Italy only. If you've been issued your passport in the UK, just put UK, Indian officials would know anyway that there are consulates, I don't think they're dumb to that extent

Comment: "they wouldn't have put the option to begin with if every Italian passport was issued in Italy only"  Bear in mind that the "they" here are the *Indian* authors of the visa application form.  All English and Welsh passports (don't know about Scottish) are issued by the Passport office in Peterborough.  In contrast German passports are issued by the local municipality.  The Indians want to know where a German passport was issued, even if the field contains no useful information for an English passport.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Anyway your point seemingly doesn't contradict what I wrote, because the option put in the website includes even [country] passports issued in [name country], so I don't understand.

Comment: Local municipality or passport office isn't relevant, because the option states "place of issue", so the issuance entity is not relevant here in this case. I was addressing an other thing.

Comment: "The place of issue" for English passports is always "Peterborough", the "place of issue" for my neighbour's passport will be "<our village>".

Comment: Then you put your village's name. By the way there's no such thing as a English or Welsh passport. There are only British passports in the UK.

Comment: I am sure that UK passports for UK citizens resident in England are issued in Peterborough.  I am not nearly so sure that is true for those resident in Scotland.  I was using "English passports" as a shortcut for "passports of UK citizens resident in England".

Comment: Then the holder of a "Scottish" passport could put the name of the place they've been issued the passport in. I don't see the problem even in that case, since the place can be written and it is not from a list of options that cannot include possibly the real answer.